# Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size after upgrading to MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I recently upgraded a server to MySQL 8.0.20 from 5.7.30 and encountered this error on a query where it had never come up in the past.  It seems to be related somehow to the inclusion of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` as the error goes away once that's removed.  I've increased `sort_buffer_size` and now things seem fine but I'm left wondering why this would be suddenly happening on MySQL 8?

I can provide more detail about the particular query and schema involved if needed but my question is more of a general "*did something change in version 8 that would cause this*"?

Comment: Let's see the query, its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Either we can discuss how to avoid the problem, or the info will help isolate what might have changed in ver 8.

Comment: Thanks Rick but I've decided to just run them as separate queries as suggested in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[>  The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS()

> function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a
>   future MySQL version. As a replacement, considering executing your
>   query with LIMIT, and then a second query with COUNT(*) and without
>   LIMIT to determine whether there are additional rows. For example,
>   instead of these queries:
>
> ```
> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
> ```
>
> Use these queries instead:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> tbl_name WHERE id > 100;
> ```
>
> COUNT(*) is subject to certain optimizations. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>   causes some optimizations to be disabled.][1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html)

Comment: thanks I'll look into that.  however it still doesn't quite explain why I would be getting a fatal error with settings that otherwise worked fine in mysql 5.7.